# What conditions should be satisfied for a rational function to be a moment generating function?

Tags: pr.probability, moments

I have a table of points at which a moment generating function is evaluated (for points $t_0,t_1,t_2,\ldots,t_n$ I know $M(t_0), M(t_1), M(t_2),\ldots,M(t_n)$).

I've approximated these tabular function with a rational function.

And I want to recreate PDF from this MGF (because it is unknown).

But clearly not every function can be a moment generating function.

So I wonder what conditions should I add in order to find a rational function that can be a moment generating function?

Comment: There's a necessary and sufficient positive definiteness condition analogous to Bochner's theorem for characteristic functions (i.e. Fourier transform instead of Laplace), see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moment_problem#Existence.  But it's not very easy to check.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possible approach here is as follows.

Note that the m.g.f. $M_{a,b}$ of the gamma distribution with parameters $a,b>0$ is given by the formula
$$M_{a,b}(t)=(1-bt)^{-a}$$
for real $t<1/b$ (with $M_{a,b}(t)=\infty$ for real $t\ge1/b$). So, the m.g.f. $M_{a,b}$ is rational on the interval $(-\infty,1/b)$ if $a$ is a positive integer.

For real $c,d>0$, letting now
$$N_{c,d}(t)=(1+dt)^{-c}$$
for real $t>-1/b$ (with $N_{c,d}(t)=\infty$ for real $t\le-1/d$), we see that $N_{c,d}$ is the m.g.f. of (the distribution of) the random variable (r.v.) $-X$ such that $X$ is a gamma r.v. with parameters $c,d$.

So, any finite mixture
$$\tilde M:=\sum_{i=1}^k p_i M_{a_i,b_i}
+\sum_{j=1}^l q_j N_{c_j,d_j} \tag{1}\label{1}$$
of such m.g.f.'s -- with any positive real $p_i$'s and $q_j$'s such that $\sum_{i=1}^k p_i+\sum_{j=1}^l q_j =1$, any positive real numbers $b_i$ and $d_j$, and any positive integers $a_i$ and $c_j$ -- will be a rational m.g.f. on the interval $(-1/\max_{j=1}^l d_j,1/\max_{i=1}^k b_i)$.

So, you will have $k-1+k+l-1+l=2k+2l-2$ positive real "degrees of freedom" and $k+l$ positive integral "degrees of freedom" to fit a rational  m.g.f. of the form \eqref{1} to your $n+1$ "data points" $(t_0,M(t_0)),\dots,(t_n,M(t_n))$.

Now, the p.d.f. corresponding to the m.g.f. $\tilde M$ in \eqref{1} is
$$\tilde f:=\sum_{i=1}^k p_i f_{a_i,b_i}
+\sum_{j=1}^l q_j g_{c_j,d_j},$$
where $f_{a,b}$ and $g_{c,d}$ are the p.d.f.'s corresponding to the m.g.f.'s $M_{a,b}$ and $N_{c,d}$, respectively:
$$f_{a,b}(x)=\frac{x^{a-1}e^{-x/b}1(x>0)}{\Gamma(a)b^a},\quad 
g_{c,d}(x)=\frac{(-x)^{c-1}e^{x/d}1(x<0)}{\Gamma(c)d^c}$$
for real $x$.

---

To illustrate how  flexible model \eqref{1} is, suppose that your data points were $(t_j,M(t_j))$ for $j=0,\dots,8$, where $t_j:=t_0+jh$, $t_0:=-19/12$, $h:=1/3$, and $M$ is the m.g.f. of the mixture of two normal distributions:

- one, taken with weight $2/5$, is with mean $-2$ and standard deviation $1/2$;
- the other one, taken with weight $1-2/5=3/5$, is with mean $3/2$ and standard deviation $1$.

Let $\tilde M$ be of the form \eqref{1}, with $k=1$, $l=1$, $p_1=0.56$, $q_1=1-p_1$, $a_1=5$, $b_1=0.338$, $c_1=15$, and $d_1=0.128$.

Shown below are the $9$ data points and the graph of $\tilde M$ over the interval $[t_0,t_0+8h]=[-19/12,13/12]$.

[image]

We see that even with $k=1$ and $l=1$ in \eqref{1} we get an almost perfect fit.

Comment: Thank you very much! We assume that empirical MGF is sum of the MGFs of the Gamma distributions. But how do I recreate the PDF? Sum of PDFs is the product of MGF's, not sum.

Comment: @PaulR : The p.d.f. corresponding to the mixture (not the sum) of m.g.f.'s is the mixture (not the sum) of p.d.f.'s corresponding to the mixed m.g.f.'s. This follows from the formula $M(t)=\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{tx}f(x)\,dx$, where $M$ is the m.g.f. and $f$ is the corresponding p.d.f. You seem to be confusing this with the completely unrelated fact that the m.g.f. of the sum of independent **r.v.'s** (not of the sum of p.d.f.'s!) is the product of the m.g.f.'s of the r.v.'s. I have now added these details to the answer.

Comment: Possibly, I don't know what the word "mixture" here means. From my point of view it is just a linear combination of MGFs.

Comment: UPDATE: I've found an article about mixture distribution. The question is the following: if MGF is defined for $t\lt\frac{1}{b}$ then $(1-bt)^{-a}$ is positive. Can we really approximate a rational function by a sum of non-negative rational functions?

Comment: @PaulR : (i) Your question was to "find a rational function that can be a moment generating function". This is done in formulas (1) and (2). (ii) Never before you had asked "Can we really approximate a rational function by a sum of non-negative rational functions?". And indeed that is not a problem, because any m.g.f. is $>0$; so, any rational m.g.f. is **already** a **nonnegative** rational function.

Comment: I just managed to approximate my tabulated data by some rational function. And then arised a question is this rational function an MGF. So, you answered that rational function can be an MGF. But what I need is to approximate my data with rational function. It is well done with any rational function, but I want to approximate it with rational MGF.

Comment: @PaulR : Your approach -- to first fit the data to some rational function that is not an m.g.f. -- was not a good idea at all. The much better idea is to fit the data right away to an **m.g.f. that is rational** over the range of the data. This also answers your stated question: ""find a rational function that can be a moment generating function". Also, I have now simplified the answer, quite a bit, with a simple and explicit expression for the p.d.f., and the fit is now almost perfect.

Comment: Thank you very much!